# Explanation for recurrence relation of a counting problem

Tags: combinatorics

This is a problem from a programming contest.

A permutaion of numbers from $1$ to $n$ is valid if the first element is $1$ and the absolute difference of all neighboring elements is $\leq2$ Count the number of valid permutations of length $n$.

I found the recurrence relation for this problem is:
$dp[x] = dp[x-1] + dp[x-3] + 1$ 
$dp[1] = dp[2] = 1$ and $dp[3] = 2$  are the base conditions.
where $dp[x]$ is defined as the number of valid permutations of lenth $x$.

Please explain how the recurrence is derived for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $P_n$ be the set of valid permutations of $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and let $Q_n'$ is the set of valid permutations of $[n]$ that begin $12$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $a_n=|P_n|$ and $b_n=|Q_n|$. (Thus, $a_n$ is your $dp[n]$.)

Let $(12p_3\ldots p_n)$ be a permutation of $[n]$ in $Q_n$. If we remove the initial $1$ and subtract $1$ from each of the remaining $n-1$ entries, we get a valid permutation of $[n-1]$. Conversely, if $(1q_2\ldots q_{n-1})$ is a valid permutation of $[n-1]$, and we set $p_{k+1}=q_k+1$ for $k=2,\ldots,n-1$, the resulting permutation $(12p_3\ldots p_n)$ is in $Q_n$. It follows that $b_n=a_{n-1}$.

Every permutation in $P_n\setminus Q_n$ begins with $13$. (Why?) Let $c_n$ be the number of valid permutations of $[n]$ that begin with $132$. An argument similar to that of the previous paragraph shows that there is a bijection between these permutations and $P_{n-3}$, the set of valid permutations of $n-3$, so $c_n=a_{n-3}$.

If $d_n$ is the number of valid permutations of $[n]$ that begin with $13$ but not with $132$, then clearly

$$a_n=b_n+c_n+d_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+d_n\;,$$

and we’re done if we can show that $d_n=1$.

Let $\pi=(13p_3\ldots p_n)$ be a valid permutation of $[n]$ that begins with $13$ but not with $132$.

- Show that $p_n=2$ and $p_{n-1}=4$.
- Show that if we remove the first and last elements of $\pi$ and subtract $2$ from each of the remaining $n-2$ elements, we get a valid permutation of $[n-2]$ that begins with $13$ but not with $132$.
- Prove by induction that for each $n\ge 4$ there is exactly one valid permutation that begins with $13$ but not with $132$.

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks for answering.

Comment: @StupidMan: You’re welcome.